# window.setInterval from inside an object

Tags: javascript

I'm currently having an issue where I have a javascript object that is trying to use setInterval to call a private function inside of itself. However, it can't find the object when I try to call it. I have a feeling that it's because window.setInterval is trying to call into the object from outside but doesn't have a reference to the object. FWIW - I can't get it to work with the function being public either.

The basic requirement is that I may need to have multiple instances of this object to track multiple uploads that are occurring at once. If you have a better design than the current one or can get the current one working then I'm all ears.

The following code is meant to continuously ping a web service to get the status of my file upload:

```
var FileUploader = function(uploadKey) {
    var intervalId;

    var UpdateProgress = function() {
        $.get('someWebService', {},
        function(json) {
            alert('success');
        });
    };

    return {
        BeginTrackProgress: function() {
            intervalId = window.setInterval('UpdateProgress()', 1500);
        },

        EndTrackProgress: function() {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    };
};
```

This is how it is being called:

```
var fileUploader = new FileUploader('myFileKey');
fileUploader.BeginTrackProgress();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this

```
 intervalId = window.setInterval(UpdateProgress, 1500);
```

setInterval with a literal argument will `eval` this in the global scope where `UpdateProgress` is not accessible.

Comment: I didn't know if setInterval allowed passing args like that because all of the examples passed strings. Good to know...

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working for me. It no longer throws an error but it never calls that function either...

Comment: @Keith Rousseau: I don't suppose there's some parts of the code simplified for the purposes of the question?

Comment: @Andy: This certainly is just a fragment of the code, but that part isn't simplified at all. If I call setInterval within an anonymous function then it seems to work. It doesn't like the direct function reference though.

Comment: Sounds like UpdateProgress hasn't been defined when the setInterval is run, but is set when the first invocation of the anonymous function is.

Comment: In the interest of not trusting examples, is it a good practise in this case to have `UpdateProgress` as an **object CamelCase** rather than a **var camelCase**? Since `UpdateProgress` is not really an object definition? I'm asking: should `UpdateProgress` be instead represented as `updateProgress`?

Comment: @cottsak If you feel using camelCase will help you not call a method as a constructor, then go ahead :)

Comment: @Sean Ok, so the convention isn't so mainstream then? It's "whatever works for you"?

Comment: @Cottsak, no it is definitely a convention, but don't feel forced to do so even if everyone else is (unless you want to share it:)

Answer (score 2):

Because it is an `eval` expression, it does not have access to the scope that setInterval is created in.  Try:

```
intervalId = window.setInterval(UpdateProgress, 1500)
```

It is generally good practice to avoid `eval` style expressions wherever possible.  For instance, if you wanted to call several functions from the same timer, you would use an anonymous function instead of a string.

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    function1();
    function2();
}, 1500)
```

See also

- [Why is using javascript eval() a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)
- [Anonymous function - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)

Comment: Yeah, I agree that eval is evil. I never really use setInterval and all of the examples seem to pass in a string.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Andy E's head (I can't upvote yet, doh!)

Another gotcha that could get you is if you use `this` from within the called function.

Then doing exactly what Andy has with this addition should get you by.

```
var that = this;
window.setInterval(function() {
    function1.apply(that);
    function2.apply(that);
}, 1500);
```