# jQuery slideshow stops after one picture in custom Wordpress template

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, templates, slideshow

See title. It seems to load fine and transitions nicely into one picture, but then refuses to work after that.

When I used Chrome to check and see what's wrong, it told me it didn't recognize the slideSwitch function, even though things worked fine when I tested it out locally.

Anyway, I hope the masters here at stackoverflow will be able to help my feeble minded self.

Thanks in advance.

jQuery code:

```
$(function slideSwitch() {
     var $active = $('#slideshow img.active');

     if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow img:last');

     var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow img:first');

     $active.addClass('last-active');

     $next.css({
         opacity: 0.0
     }).addClass('active').animate({
         opacity: 1.0
     }, 2000, function () {
         $active.removeClass('active last-active');
     });
 });

 $(function () {
     setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
 });
```

And here's it's accompanying CSS:

```
#slideshow {
    height:327px;
    border:thick #000;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#slideshow img {
     border: solid #000000 10px;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     z-index: 8;
}

#slideshow img.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow img.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: hey can you pop-in some html as well, might be able to help you out, cheers! If you can't give HTML see this example here -  **working** http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/D6BGj/  (and cheer up brother everyone are good including you so no one is feeble mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because setinterval is an eval.

So do this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    slideSwitch();
}, 5000);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/cxPU6/

Read more here: [window.setInterval from inside an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865332/window-setinterval-from-inside-an-object)

I get the same problem over and over again :)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! Worked out perfectly! If there was some way to give you an apple or something via webs, I would definitely do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setInterval( function(){
   slideSwitch();
}, 5000 );
```